# Render template located in a unregistered folder in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

On my site i have `demo` template in specific folder:

```python
project_root
├── project
│   ├── design               # templates
│   │   ├── demo             # template folder
│   │   │   └── index.html   # template file
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── some_app
│   └── ...
└── manage.py
```

I have tried to use `TemplateView` to render my `demo/index.html` from specific url but Django fails to find my template, even if i add `/project/design` to `TEMPLATE_DIRS`  or `TEMPLATES`.

I need to render template using `demo/index.html` string having templates in `/project/design` folder. How do i do that?

Comment: Why do you wanna put your templates in this folder? why not in `project_root/templates/` or `project_root/app_name/templates`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in the right template engine that you use, for example **DjangoTemplate**, this directory.

E.g (`settings.py` file) :

```python
from unipath import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/project/design/',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Check that `BASE_DIR` variable corresponds to the folder that contains all your apps.**

After that,rend your template with :

```pytho
return render(request, 'demo/index.html')
```

**Best practice** : Put your templates in `project_root/templates/<app_name>/` or in `templates/<app_name>` folder of each apps.

Read this for more information about templates : [Django - Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/)

Comment: Thank you! I've tried that but didn't notice that in the end of `settings.py` there was default `TEMPLATES` definition so my was not applied.

Comment: Is it working? Why do you wanna put your templates in this folder? why not in project_root/templates/ or project_root/app_name/templates?

Comment: Working fine (but `{}` is not needed for `render`). I love this structure. Maybe i was unclear, all i change is `templates` to `design`, its located in project folder as usual

Comment: cool :) yeah, forget to delete it, i will update the anwser. Thank you